# Power BI, Turnover formula for specific time period (year, quarter, etc.)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to build a Power BI report to calculate employee turnover. My data is spread across two queries - one has all the employee data like start dates, termination dates, IDs, etc., and the second one is a calendar table that includes fiscal year, fiscal month, and specific dates.

Here's where I need help: I want to add a slicer to the report where users can choose a specific year or quarter. Once a time period is selected, the report should show the turnover percentage for that specific period.

The challenge is figuring out how to make Power BI count only the active employees up to and including that year (using the start date or counting rows where termination date is empty) when a specific year like 2021 is selected. Similarly, I need to count only those employees who left during that specific time period, excluding the ones who left before or after.

I hope this explanation makes the issue a bit clearer. Any guidance would be appreciated!

`TerminationRate =` 
`VAR MaxDate = MAX('Calendar Table'[Date])`
`VAR HCCount = CALCULATE( COUNT('Artificial Data Dump'[ID]),   USERELATIONSHIP('Calendar Table'[Date], 'Artificial Data Dump'[Start Date]))`
`VAR LeaversCount = CALCULATE( COUNT('Artificial Data Dump'[Termination Date]),  USERELATIONSHIP('Calendar Table'[Date], 'Artificial Data Dump'[Termination Date]))`
`RETURN DIVIDE(LeaversCount, HCCount)`

Regrettably, this formula doesn't accomplish the task.